# Prevent Context.Database.SqlQuery<> parameters from sending default instead of null

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Context.Database.SqlQuery in my MVC EF project to do a query (not stored procedure) and have a couple of parameters that I want to be null.

But when it gets sent I changes the parameter from null to default.

How do I prevent that?

The procedure starts out as:

```
var result = _context.Database.SqlQuery<ReviewProposalsExport>(@"
DECLARE @DisplayStatus bit = 0,
        @DisplayDecision bit = 0                
...
ORDER BY PrefixDescription, Prefix, SubmissionDate,  CourseNumber, CourseTitle",
new SqlParameter("Status", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25) { Value = status },
new SqlParameter("Type", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = type },
new SqlParameter("BeginDate", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = beginDate },
new SqlParameter("BeginDate", SqlDbType.Date) { Value = endDate }
);
```

But the SQL that get's sent is:

```
exec sp_executesql N'
DECLARE @DisplayStatus bit = 0,
        @DisplayDecision bit = 0                
...
ORDER BY PrefixDescription, Prefix, SubmissionDate,  CourseNumber, CourseTitle',
N'@Status varchar(25),@Type int,@BeginDate date,@BeginDate date',
@Status='All',@Type=0,@BeginDate=default,@BeginDate=default
```

This causes an error. There should be no default if not a stored procedure.

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Check if the Date value is null, if yes, then set your parameter value to DBNull.Value. Null in C# is different than the database NULL.

Comment: Something like { value = (object)endDate ?? DBNull.Value }  should work. or you can use simple 'If else' to create your paramter.

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Comment: Added it as an answer to help others. Please accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the Date value is null, if yes, then set your parameter value to DBNull.Value. Null in C# is different than the database NULL.

Something like:

`new SqlParameter("BeginDate", SqlDbType.Date) { value = (object)endDate ?? DBNull.Value }`

Or you can use simple 'If else' to create your parameter.